# Calling a python function from a shell script from another directory

Tags: python, bash

i'm trying to use a function from a python script and store it to a variable in a shell script from another directory,here's the visual representation of the directories:

```
    xxx/
        aaa.sh
    yyy/
        sample.py
```

here's the code of the sample.py

```
    import ConfigParser

    def getval(section, key):
    config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
    config.read("sample.config")
    return config.get(section, key)
```

and here is some part of the aaa.sh

```
    #!/bin/sh

    Path = $(python -c 'import imp; lp = imp.load.source('sample', 'path/to/sample.py'), print lp.getval('section_1', 'key_1')')

    some code.......

    echo $Path
```

my problem was i don't get any value of the Path,i think i have mistake on how will i call the python script function,i don't know what part is that.
can anyone help me. thanks in advance.

i combined the idea of EOL from this question [Calling a Python function from a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567526/calling-a-python-function-from-a-shell-script) and the idea of Sebastian Rittau from this question [How to import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path).

Comment: i'm sorry but i'm not familiar with shell script that's why i'm asking,sorry again.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Path=$(python -c 'import imp; lp = imp.load.source("sample", "path/to/sample.py"); print lp.getval("section_1", "key_1")')
```