# How to run python function from shell script

Tags: python, shell

This is my shell script, and I want to run the method `foo(param)`:

```
#!/bin/sh    
python /Users/username/Desktop/forTrump/test.py
```

How would I run a function inside `test.py` using the shell script above?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a Python function from a shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567526/calling-a-python-function-from-a-shell-script)

Answer (score 1):

```
python -c 'import test; print test.foo(param)'
```

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer can you mark it as answered

Comment: Please start writing halfway-decent answers with explanations, not just code dumps, and stop hassling OPs to accept.

Comment: I would like to run this in a shell script with absolute path "/Users/username/Desktop/forTrump/test.py" I am not printing anything just running the method, which will run to a file, should I still include "print"?