# Unable to call python function using shell script

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell

I am using one shell script to call python function -

```
python -c 'import create_table; create_table.createTable()'
```

This script is in "scripts" directory and create_table.py file is in another directory - "cdk"
Folder structure will look like this -

```
infra -> cdk -> create_table.py
      -> scripts -> run-script.sh
```

cdk and scripts directories are at same level inside infra directory.

When I am trying to run my script it is giving below error -

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'create_table'
```

I tried placing create_table.py file in scripts directory, but still it's giving same error.
I am referring this question - [Calling a Python function from a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567526/calling-a-python-function-from-a-shell-script)
Can anyone please help me out? Am I missing something here?

Update - create_table.py code

```
import boto3

def createTable():
    print("createTable function")
```

There is no class in this python file.

Answer (score 0):

Your script and package are in different directories. You need to add `__init__.py` to your cdk. This will tell python it's a module. 
Then run 
`python -c 'import ..cdk.create_table; create_table.createTable()`

Comment: Do I need to add anything in __init__.py file?
And do I need to add two dots before cdk.create_table

Comment: `__init.py__` is a empty file indicating directory will acts as module. You have to give relative or absolute path. Add .. while importing indicates it has to get out from scripts and go to cdk

Answer (score 0):

Import the module in a correct way

also use `createTable()` directly NOT `create_table.createTable()`

```
python -c 'import sys; sys.path.insert(0, "../cdk"); from create_table import createTable; createTable()'
```

Comment: There is no class in create_table.py file.
So "from create_table import createTable; " will not work

Comment: @Nitesh You call the function. you did not import the whole file. I tested on my shell and `create_table.createTable()` gave an error while `createTable()` did not

Comment: I have added this line in my script - 

python -c 'import sys; sys.path.insert(0, "infra/cdk"); from create_table import createTable; createTable()' and it is giving this error - 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'create_table'

Comment: Thanks for updating absolute path. I will try it and will let you know.

Comment: see the edit  `python -c 'import sys; sys.path.insert(0, "../cdk"); from create_table import createTable; createTable()'`

Comment: I have updated my script as per your suggestion but still it is giving same error - 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'create_table'

Comment: You said that it is working at your end. Could you please share your code.

Comment: Ok. please wait

Comment: this is directory structure https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFahe.png

Comment: `cat infra/scripts/run-script.sh` `python -c 'import sys; sys.path.insert(0, "../cdk"); from create_table import createTable; createTable()'`

Comment: `cat infra/cdk/create_table.py` `def createTable():
        print("Hello World")`

Comment: `~/infra/scripts$ bash run-script.sh` returns Hello world

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202692/discussion-between-nitesh-and-ahmed-abdelazim).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you're running into problems because imports depend on the path from which you're calling the `run-script.sh`. A solution to this might be adding:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    createTable()
```

at the end of `create_table.py` and replacing the content of `run-script.sh` with:

```
#!/bin/bash
pth=`dirname $0`
python3 $pth/../cdk/create_table.py
```

After doing so you should be able run it from any path you want/need to.